# Best way to handle relation data on subfilter with type-graphql

Tags: graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

I have question about relational data query between graphql / typeorm.
Best way to explain is giving an example :)

For the purpose of my question i using prisma API for example (https://www.graphqlbin.com/v2/6RQ6TM)
This API is an example of StarWars GraphQL API

If i want to get all film and associated characters i do query like this:

#### CASE A

```
 {
   allFilms{
    title
    characters{
        name
    }
   }
 }
```

in this case relational database call can be do in one shot, retrieve film and character together (sql select with join)
My question is how keep sql performance when filter is added in query like this

#### CASE B

```
{
   allFilms{
    title
    characters(filter: {name_contains: "PO"}){
        name
    }
   }
 }
```

In this case it seems that we have to do this with FieldResolver and do other database call to retrieve child

To clarify please see examples below:

CASE A (SIMPLE IMPLEMENTATION)
in case of nodejs backend in typescript and typeorm ORM we could this like this:
Entity:

```
    @Entity()
    @ObjectType()
    export class Film { 

        @PrimaryColumn()
        @Field(type => ID, { description: 'The id of the object.'})
        id: string;

        @Column()
        @Field({ description: 'The title of this film'})
        title: string;

        .....

        @ManyToMany(type => Person, person => person.films )
        @JoinTable({ name: 'film_person' })   
        @Field(type => [Person], { nullable: true }) 
        characters?: Person[];
    }
```

Resolver:

```
    @Resolver(of => Film)
    export class FilmResolvers { 

      constructor(private readonly filmService: FilmService) {}

      @Query(returns => [Film])  
      async allFilms(@Args() args: QueryAllFilmDTO): Promise<Film[]> {    
        return this.filmService.findAll(args);
      }
    }
```

CASE B (EXTENDED IMPLEMENTATION)

Resolver:

```
 @Resolver(of => Film)
 export class FilmResolvers {

  constructor(
    private readonly filmService: FilmService,    
    @InjectRepository(Person) private readonly personRepository: Repository<Person>,
    ) {}

  @ResolveProperty(type => [Person])  
  async characters(@Parent() film: Film, @Args() args: PersonQueryAllDTO) {

    // Low Performance in this case 
    const persons = await this.personRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('person')
      .leftJoin('person.films', 'film','film.id = :films_param',{films_param: [film.id]})      
      .getMany();

    return persons;
  }

  @Query(returns => [Film])  
  async allFilms(@Args() args: QueryAllFilmDTO): Promise<Film[]> {
    this.detectRelation(info.operation.selectionSet);        
    return this.filmService.findAll(args);
  }
}
```

The probleme here that we do a manual join (two database call)
I thinking about other solution but i need your review:

CASE B (OTHER EXTENDED IMPLEMENTATION)
my goal retrieve extendend graphql request info, detect relation in query and construct sql query with join

```
 @Resolver(of => Film)
 export class FilmResolvers { 

  constructor(
    private readonly filmService: FilmService,  
    @InjectRepository(Person) private readonly personRepository: Repository<Person>,
    ) {}


    @Query(returns => [Film])  
  async allFilms(@Args() args: QueryAllFilmDTO, @Info() info: GraphQLResolveInfo): Promise<Film[]> {

    const relations: string[] = [];
    this.getRelations(info.operation.selectionSet, (relation) =>{
      relations.push(relation);
    });

    return this.filmService.findAll(args, relations);
  }




  private getRelations(selectionSetNode: SelectionSetNode, callback: relationCallback, level=0){      
      selectionSetNode.selections.forEach( (subSelection) => {                
        if(subSelection.kind === 'Field'){
          const fieldNode = subSelection as FieldNode;          
          if(fieldNode.selectionSet){
            if(level)              
              callback(fieldNode.name.value);            
            this.getRelations(fieldNode.selectionSet, callback, ++level);        
          }
        }        
      });
  }
}
```

is it a good option ? or is there any other way to optimize database call ?